# Mess with tty, how to configure it for text login and tty7 for graphics?

Tags: graphics, login, plymouth

It shows graphical login on tty2 after Ubuntu start. I do login, all fine. Then I press Ctr-Alt-F1 - I see another graphical login. So `gdm3` run on 1 and 2 consoles. 3-6 consoles are text login. 7th console shows short(4 lines) of boot log. How I can reconfigure it? Prevent X start twice, and have it on 7th console, or another but only one?

May be this happens after I play with `plymouth` themes. I try to turn on ubuntu-text theme, and later one downloaded. How to correctly reconfigure or delete it?

**Update:**
Do run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure plymouth && sudo update-initramfs -u` , after that login appears on tty7, I do login, check another tty's and found X login on tty1 too, tty2-tty6 work as intended. Who start X login on tty1? *Where are config files for that?*

**Update2:**
Disabled Wayland in `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. Are there other configs? Didn't found.
Removed splash from /etc/default/grub, reboot, gdm at tty1, text terminals 2-6, tty7 empty. After login, session opened on tty7,  then gdm login appears on tty1. May be this is designed behavior? Anyway I don't need this login as there are only one user. Also if this matters, I log into X session, not Wayland.

Comment: System boot slowdowns noticeable